# What is the best tool to draw a linear function?

Tags: graph, draw

I have y = 2x + 1
Now I need to draw this linear function. Does exist a good library for that?

Comment: This type of question is [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please read the [help]

Answer (score -1):

For simplicity you can use google as follows: plot 2x+1
[image]